# Homebrew - can't install Sphinx

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I'm trying to get Sphinx (and thinking Sphinx working). It have worked before - but it stopped working tonight after my colleague installed Node, php and some other stuff.

It first complained about a locked pid file:

```
FATAL: failed to lock pid file
```

After this I tried to reinstall `Sphinx`:

```
brew uninstall sphinx
```

And:

```
brew install sphinx.
```

I already have `mysql` so I skipped `--mysql`. This results in the following:

```
This is not sphinx - the Python Documentation Generator.
To install sphinx-python: use pip or easy_install,

Sphinx has been compiled with libstemmer support.

Sphinx depends on either MySQL or PostreSQL as a datasource.

You can install these with Homebrew with:
  brew install mysql
    For MySQL server.

  brew install mysql-connector-c
    For MySQL client libraries only.

  brew install postgresql
    For PostgreSQL server.

We don't install these for you when you install this formula, as
we don't know which datasource you intend to use.
```

When running `searchd` I get this:

```
FATAL: no readable config file (looked in   /usr/local/Cellar/sphinx/2.2.6/etc/sphinx.conf, ./sphinx.conf).
```

And when trying to start `thinking-sphinx` for my rails app I get:

```
Failed to start searchd. Check the log files for more information.
```

And the log file still says:

```
FATAL: failed to lock pid file
```

I'm not sure what is causing this, or how I can fix it. Thought that reinstalling `Sphinx` would be enough - but I'm stuck at square one.

Any ideas on how I can get it to work again?

Comment: The 'locked pid file' suggests that searchd is still running, when its trying to start it again. So the previous one hasnt shut down. Try stopping searchd completely, **then** reinstall.

Comment: Also, you can manually start Sphinx for your Rails app by running the following: `searchd --pidfile --config config/development.sphinx.conf` (which is essentially what `rake ts:start` does) - and the output of that will likely be more helpful than the rake task.

Comment: Thanks @pat you're a hero as always! Doing `searchd --pidfile --config config/development.sphinx.conf` made it work, and now `rake ts:start` also works.

Comment: I wonder if something else that happened along the way fixed things - there really shouldn't be any difference between manual searchd call and ts:start, beyond the extra output. But great to know it's working! :)

Answer (score 1):

How about uninstalling sphinx and giving this a go:

```
brew install sphinx --pgsql --mysql
```